# How to postpone/delay/schedule incoming messages in Gmail

Tags: gmail

Is there any way to postpone/delay/schedule incoming messages in Gmail?
I can see there is third party solutions like boomerang, etc but this way I rely on third party service.

What I am really looking for is some sort of solution that part of Gmail and it will be applied in case if I am using web interface, Gmail app in my mobile phone.

Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

GMail does not currently have this feature.

You may Send Feedback and suggest it for future addition. Send Feedback by going to clicking 'Help' from the 'Gear' settings menu, then choosing 'Send Feedback' at the bottom. [[Source](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6142372?hl=en)]

Answer (score 1):

[Inbox by Gmail](https://inbox.google.com) is a new interface for Gmail from Google currently in wide preview. Among its features is "snooze", which allows you to take a message from your inbox and send it away until tomorrow, next week, "someday", or a custom date/time.

There are Android and iOS apps, as well as a web interface. It's not classic Gmail, but it's still Google, so there's no third-party.

Comment: I want to postpone the receiving emails not send email

Comment: That's exactly what it does. That's to say, a message arrives in your inbox. You don't want to deal with it right now, so you "snooze" it until a later time.

Comment: Yeah I can see that I can snooze each incoming email which is not what I want. What I want is to postpone the whole inbox so all incoming emails will be showing only in a specific time

Comment: I'm afraid that's not something you can do without some third-party app or service.